# Getting the original value of a div after changing it with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class, object

I'm trying to recreate a game mechanic I've seen. The mechanic is a gun reload.

Currently, I have it set up so when you click on a div that has the class ".weapon" it will count down the "ammo", if you get to 0 it will say no ammo.

If you click and hold the ".weapon" for x amount of time then it will do the reload.

The issue which of there are always many when I do anything -_- is that when I want to reload weapon 3 for example, I don't know how to get the original value for the "ammo" that that div(".weapon") started with.

I've tried to set the value in a var but I'm not sure if this would need to be done in an object or something like that maybe?

The thing that is most confusing me apart from everything is the jQuery $(this).

For example 5 divs with the class ".weapon"
I know you can make a click function (or anything other) hide the class ".weapon" individually depending on which of the divs you click instead of hiding them all. But with what I'm trying to do with a var it's obviously not the same, well I don't think it is anyway.

I'm very sure everything else apart from the issue I'm highlighting is also not done right so if you want to let me know how bad it is please feel free lol.

Not sure if that makes any sense because I'm also not great at trying to explain myself as well. (Not in text anyway)

If you want to help and I need to explain anything any further please let me know and thank you for even reading this if you did.

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="weapon center">
    <div class="ammo">5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="weapon center">
    <div class="ammo">8</div>
  </div>
  <div class="weapon center">
    <div class="ammo">10</div>
  </div>
  <div class="weapon center">
    <div class="ammo">12</div>
  </div>
  <div class="message"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper{
  width:40%;
  margin:30px auto;
}

.weapon{
  float:left;
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
  border: 2px dashed #000;
  padding:5px;
  margin:5px;
  line-height:80px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var n;
  var currentReload = 0;
  var reloaded = false;

  $('.weapon').ready(function(){
    bb = $(this);
    bcurrentAmmo = bb.find('.ammo').html();
  });

  function reload(bb,bcurrentAmmo) {
    if(currentReload <= 2){
      currentReload++;
    }else{
      bb.find('.ammo').html(bcurrentAmmo);
      reloaded = true;
      clearInterval(n);
    }
  }

  $('.weapon').mousedown(function(){
    reloaded = false;
    n = setInterval(function() { reload(bb,bcurrentAmmo);}, 100);
  }).mouseup(function() {
    currentReload = 0;
    clearInterval(n);
  });

  $('.weapon').click(function(){
    if(reloaded == false){
      b = $(this);
      currentAmmo = b.find('.ammo').html();
      if(currentAmmo >= 1){
        currentAmmo--;
      }else{
        $('.message').html("No Ammo! Click & Hold To Reload")
      }
      b.find('.ammo').html(currentAmmo);
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a attribute to the element labeled "maxAmmo". You can then use `element.getAttribute("maxAmmo")` to get the original ammo value.

Comment: That just seems to give me the same issue when I run it. I think it is overwriting the value.